# Redirect user after session timeout and displaying error message

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm using below JSP code to redirect the user after session timeout.

But, my requirement is to display a message on the "redirect url page" that the session has timed out and user needs to relogin..So, basically I need to pass a request object that I can use to display the message.How can I do that?

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="<%= session.getMaxInactiveInterval() %>; URL=redirect url" />
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985250/notify-user-about-session-timeout-in-java-ee